# becomeFirstResponder Memory Problems

Tags: ios, memory-management, uitextfield

I have a hidden UITextField that when a the user is required to enter a character from the keyboard is sent:

```
[txtField becomeFirstResponder]
```

This text field has an event on editing changed that then calls a function to handle what was entered how I need it.

The user then selects an okay button that calls the following:

```
txtBox.text = @"";

[txtBox resignFirstResponder ];
```

I have tracked some memory problems all the way through to the line `[txtField becomeFirstResponder]`. When this is called, my Apps memory usage doubles on the spot and I receive a memory warning (even though code run). If I remove it (I have no keyboard of course!) but the memory issue goes away. I have read and tried a few approaches like removing the keyboard at Delegate level but without success. I am almost at the point of creating my own Keyboard.

Even though it is a lot I could probably work with this increase providing it would get properly released once I dismiss the keyboard - but it doesn't. The footprint of the App just gets heavier and heavier and for the life of me I cannot work out why.

First question is, is it possible that above is causing me the problem? I presume it is unlikely.

If not, any suggestions where to look / why I would receive such a rapid increase?

Heres a screenshot of Instruments - red line indicates where I call becomeFirstResponder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7PaU.png
(they wont let me upload it - sorry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a good way to track memory leaks/problems. If there is a memory leak, instruments will show a leak, and that you can fix. You shouldn't assume the OS will free up memory just because you closed the keyboard (if anything, it probably is lazy loaded and cached). 
Though I never had a problem with that, It is possible that your memory footprint increases when you show the keyboard. You didn't say how much memory is actually being used, so I will assume it is a small app and doubling that when opening a keyboard should be fine. 
The OS caches all frozen open apps so memory is always tight. When receiving memory warnings clear what you can and let the OS handle the rest. If needed it will kill background apps. It doesn't mean that something is wrong with your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. the app was getting memory warnings even though there was no leaks. I have been trying to drop the footprint and traced a large bulk of it to the keyboard that as you say, wasn't cleaning up after itself and just caching. To control this, I've just created a simple keyboard with the characters I needed. This let me control the memory accordingly and was a bonus as I don't now need to check the input from the real keyboard. Probably not the best approach to run away from the issue but is working with other added bonuses. Will accept your answer for the info tho. Ralph